# Add item to the top of LinearLayout Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a `LinearLayout` inside `ScrollLayout`. I add pictures to LinearLayout programmaticaly, so user can scroll through them. I need an option to add a picture to the top of LinearLayout, so user can see it on the top of their screen. How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there are no options other than that once you remove all current child `ImageViews` of the `LinearLayout`, then you re-add those child `ImageView`s including the new one in the order you intend.

See this [QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38210096/how-to-order-elements-inside-a-linear-layout) for more information.

Comment: That is not what I need. I'd like to add a new ImageView to the top of LinearLayout, like when using RelativeLayout I use layout_above. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: @JuliaL. Perhaps, I got what you needed; updated my answer.

Comment: seems its the only way. Thanks